# I want the boolean account set to the boolean from firestore database

Tags: flutter

I want to get the boolean from firestore and than set the boolean _account to that false/true.
Every user has different true or false so it needs to have a UID? I am starting with firestore but i don"t understand a lot. I hope you guys can help me.

This is the where the bool needs to be set:

[image: This is the where the bool needs to be set]

This is the Auth service:

[image: This is the Auth service]

This is the database user info:

[image: This is the database user info]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code. People may want to copy and play around with it to better understand your problem and that makes it very hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await users.document(await getCurrentUID).get();
    Map<String, dynamic> map = snapshot.data;
   _account = map['account'];
```

I really hope this helps.

By the way you can't use await in the build function. So if you need to load the value before a widget is build so it will be able to use this data you should consider using a [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html).